# A developer when going through a code base encounters two different syntaxes for creating a NSString with the given integer. (implemented in MRC)

Tags: ios, objective-c

**1.** `NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithInt: 10];`

**2.** `NSString *str2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithInt: 10];`

What is the difference between these methods?

Comment: The first one is most likely only by convenience, a shorthand for the second.

Answer (score 1):

The history goes to times when automatic reference counting doesn't existed.
Then Apple have created notation, that methods with prefixes `init`, `copy`, `new` returns owned pointer, that mean that you don't need to `retain` it, other methods should return autoreleased pointers. For example

```
NSString *a;
NSString *b;

@autoreleasepool {
  a = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", 1];
  b = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 2];

  NSLog(@"String a in autorelease pool is %@", a); //output: String a in autoreleasepool is 1
  NSLog(@"String b in autorelease pool is %@", b); //output: String b in autoreleasepool is 2

}

NSLog(@"String a out of autorelease pool is %@", a); //output: String a out of autorelease pool is 1
NSLog(@"String b in autorelease pool is %@", b); //crash: referencing invalid object, because b was autoreleased but variable `b` still pointing at released object
```

For proper working outside autoreleasepool variable `b` should be retained:

```
NSString *b;

@autoreleasepool {
  b = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 2] retain];
  NSLog(@"String b in autorelease pool is %@", b); //output: String b in autoreleasepool is 2
}
NSLog(@"String b out of autorelease pool is %@", b); //output: String b out of autorelease pool is 1
```

But if you use `retain` properties, you will face opposite situation: memory leaks.
Proper code will be

```
@property (retain) NSString *a;
@property (retain) NSString *b;

@autoreleaspool {
  self.a = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", 1] autorelease];
  self.b = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 2];
}
```

So exact implementation of `stringWithFormat:` is doing `alloc`+`init`+`autorelease`

Of course now when we have `ARC` we don't need think about proper object retaining and releasing.
In `ARC` first code snipped will work fine without crashes, second code snippet will work fine without memory-leaks.

So now it's just for programmer sense which one he prefer most. It's like in swift: you can write: `SomeClass(...)` or `SomeClass.init(...)`

Answer (score 0):

The first is a class factory method. See http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch04.html#_class_methods_2

The second is a genuine initializer.

The difference between them was much more obvious back in the day of manual memory management. Now that ARC exists, they are indistinguishable — which is why Swift eliminates the former.